# How to configure earlgrey to not track network calls at all?

Tags: earlgrey

Seeing this error when trying to write the tests. How to configure earlgrey to not track network calls at all?

---

Exception Details: Error Trace: [
  {
    "Description":  "Failed to execute block because idling resources below are busy.",
    "Description Glossary":    {
      "GREYAppStateTracker":  "Waiting for network requests to finish. By default, EarlGrey tracks all network requests. To change this behavior, refer to GREYConfiguration.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the link that you'd like to not be tracked, then you can use the blacklist regex configuration.

https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/91c27bb8a15e723df974f620f7f576a30a6a7484/Tests/UnitTests/Sources/NSURL%2BGREYAdditionsTest.m#L43

Comment: I tried that but did not work. As when I run the unit test, the app starts to run before actually calling the unit test's set up method and inside the set up I had the blacklist  as below\n  override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        //Add Mocks and stuff here
        GREYConfiguration.sharedInstance().setValue([".*abcserver.*"], forConfigKey: kGREYConfigKeyURLBlacklistRegex)

Comment: Can you move it to before super.setUp?

Comment: Tried but same problem. As when I start the test (1) the app starts to run, as part of this some network calls are already started (2) setup of the test is called where I tell to ignore the network. But I think from here on wards, it will ignore.. But not the network calls that already got started!

Comment: What about in an attribute constructor. Since the test depends on EG, the constructors of EG should be called before your test.

Comment: Where do I add attribute constructor? I do not want to add in main.m file. How can I add this in test code?

Comment: You can add it in a test file as well.

Comment: test file in swift? Do you have any sample? Thanks!